# Issue with Compiling Kivy App Using Buildozer: Python 2 Print Syntax in SDL2_ttf

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have been building a Kivy app for android. I have been following a tutorial but encountering lots of errors. Most of them I've been able to work through but I have no idea how to fix this one

I'm encountering an error while trying to compile the app using Buildozer. It seems to be related to Python 2 print syntax in an SDL2_ttf module. The error message suggests a missing parentheses issue:

```
...
Compiling '/home/getwe/Amelia/Ops_AMELIA/.buildozer/android/app/venv/bin/rst2man.py'...
Compiling '/home/getwe/Amelia/Ops_AMELIA/.buildozer/android/app/venv/bin/rst2html.py'...
Compiling '/home/getwe/Amelia/Ops_AMELIA/.buildozer/android/app/kivy-deps-build/kivy-dependencies/build/SDL2-2.26.4/src/joystick/sort_controllers.py'...
Compiling '/home/getwe/Amelia/Ops_AMELIA/.buildozer/android/app/kivy-deps-build/kivy-dependencies/build/SDL2_ttf-2.20.2/external/freetype/src/tools/chktrcmp.py'...
***   File "/home/getwe/Amelia/Ops_AMELIA/.buildozer/android/app/kivy-deps-build/kivy-dependencies/build/SDL2_ttf-2.20.2/external/freetype/src/tools/chktrcmp.py", line 27
    print "Usage: %s [option]" % sys.argv[0]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
...
```

I've manually corrected the print statements in chktrcmp.py, but it seems that Buildozer is reinstalling the module and reverting the changes with each build.

I've included the first half my buildozer.spec file for reference, the other half is all default.

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = AMELIA

# (str) Package name
package.name = AMELIA

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,db,ini

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd==1.1.1,bcrypt,mysql-connector-python,pillow,cffi==1.14.6,libffi,sdl2_ttf,sdl2_image,sdl2_mixer

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (list) Supported orientations
# Valid options are: landscape, portrait, portrait-reverse or landscape-reverse
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY
```

I've also ensured that SDL2_ttf and other required modules are included in my requirements. Could someone please help me understand how to resolve this issue? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!